# Does Exchange Online support MAPI Client applications

Tags: mapi, office365

I have been searching for a clear answer to a question I have about Office 365/Exchange Online. We use a MAPI application that uses a MAPI profile to send messages on behalf of the user. The Systems would already have an Exchange Online compliant version of Outlook installed locally. Is this kind of MAPI access possible with Exchange Online ?

I know there are options for enabling HTTP/RPC MAPI for the account, but the question is really whether the MAPI API on the client will work against an Exchange Online hosted mailbox (assuming MAPI is enabled for the mailbox).

Does anyone know if this is possible and if there are any limitations on what parts of the MAPI API can be used ?

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook version of MAPI fully supports ROH as of Outlook 2007.

Hosted Exchange accounts support ROH since that is the only way Outlook can access the mailbox.

The standalone version of MAPI on the other hand, was only recently updated to support ROH due to the fact that ROH and EWS are the only 2 ways to access Exchange 2013; the old fashion RPC does not work anymore. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephen_griffin/archive/2013/02/28/exchange-2013-co